# How to pass CloudFlare Browser Integrity Check with Playwright

Tags: typescript, cloudflare, playwright

Project that I am working on has integration with GitLab and in my end-to-end tests, I need to log in with GitLab in order to access the app.
However, when you go to https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in, you end up staying on this screen that says *Checking your browser before accessing gitlab.com.*

I know that there is a solution when using selenium with [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/2.1.1/)(at least for python), but I am wondering if someone succeeded passing this with Playwright.